# A question about straight lines that bisect the area of a triangle

Tags: geometry

Let $K$ be a convex subset of the Euclidean plane $E(2)$ whose boundary is a triangle. Is it true that there cannot exist 4 pairwise distinct concurrent straight lines in $E(2)$, each of which bisects the area of $K$? Many results in the literature strongly suggest that this is true, but I have not so far been able to find a theorem that actually states or implies that it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you have an angle of vertex $V$ and a point $P$ inside it. If $r$ is a line through $P$ forming a chord $QR$, then the area $s$ of triangle $VQR$ is a function of the angle $\theta=\angle VPR$. Let $\alpha=\angle QVP$ and $\beta=\angle RVP$: $\theta$ can take any value between $\beta$ and $\pi-\alpha$, and the area of triangle $VQR$ can be written as 
$s(\theta)=(\overline{VP}{}^2/2)\,f(\theta)$, where:
$$
f(\theta)=
{\sin\alpha\sin\theta\over \cos\alpha\sin\theta+\sin\alpha\cos\theta}+
{\sin\beta\sin\theta\over \cos\beta\sin\theta-\sin\beta\cos\theta}.
$$
Substituting here $t=\tan\theta$, $u=\tan\alpha$ and $v=\tan\beta$ this can be rewritten in the simpler form
$$
f(t)={tu\over t+u}+{tv\over t-v},
$$
with $t<-u$ or $t>v$.
Notice that $\lim\limits_{t\to-u}f(t)=\lim\limits_{t\to v}s=+\infty$,
while $\lim\limits_{t\to\pm\infty}f(t)=u+v$.

$f'(t)$ vanishes, in the allowed range, for $t=2uv/(u-v)$, which then corresponds to the only minimum $f_\min$ of $f(t)$ and of $f(\theta)$. For every value $y>f_\min$ the equation $f(\theta)=y$ has then exactly two solutions. See below for a typical plot of $f(\theta)$, for $\alpha=\pi/6$ and $\beta=\pi/4$.

[image]

Consider now a triangle $ABC$ of area $S$ and a point $P$ inside it. Let $A'$, $B'$ and $C'$ be the points where lines $PA$, $PB$ and $PC$ intersect $BC$, $AC$ and $AB$ respectively. A chord $QR$ of $\angle BAC$ passing through $P$ (with $Q\in AB$ and $R\in AC$) is inside the triangle only if 
$\angle APB'<\angle APR<\angle APC$. From the above discussion it follows that the area of $AQR$ can be $S/2$ only if $Area_{ABB'}>S/2$ or $Area_{ACC'}>S/2$  (I'm not considering here the special case when both areas are $S/2$, that is when $P$ is the centroid of $ABC$). In addition, there can be two different chords through $P$ bisecting the area of triangle $ABC$ only if both inequalities hold.

The same reasoning can be repeated for angles $\angle ACB$ and $\angle ABC$. In the end we find that the number of chords bisecting the area of $ABC$ is bounded by the number of triangles among $ABB'$, $ACC'$, $BAA'$, $BCC'$, $CAA'$, $CBB'$ whose area is larger than $S/2$. But those six triangles can be paired so that the sum of the triangles in each couple is $ABC$: it follows that only three among them can have an area greater than $S/2$. Hence no more than three lines passing through $P$ and bisecting the area of $ABC$ can exist.

Answer (score 6):

As @JeanMarie has mentioned, this problem is "affine invariant"; so, if we can settle it for, say, an equilateral triangle, then we will have solved it for all triangles.

Now, given $\triangle ABC$, and a particular vertex, and a continuous parameter, we can consider the family of area-bisectors that form sub-triangles with the vertex. For instance, for vertex $A$, we get triangles $\triangle AB_t C_t$ where $$B_t = A + t\;(B-A) \quad\text{and}\quad C_t := A + \frac{1}{2t}\;(C-A) \quad\text{, for}\;\;\frac{1}{2}\leq t \leq 1 \tag{1}$$
Here, because 
$$2|\triangle AB_t C_t| = |\overline{AB_t}||\overline{AC_t}|\;\sin A = t\;|\overline{AB}|\cdot\frac{1}{2t}|\overline{AC}| \sin A = \frac{1}{2}|\overline{AB}||\overline{AC}|\sin A = |\triangle ABC|$$
we have that $\overline{B_tC_t}$ is in fact an area-bisector. (Note that the restrictions on $t$ guarantee that this bisector crosses the sides adjacent to $A$.)

If we take our triangle to have vertices $A = (1, 0)$, $B = (\cos\frac{2\pi}{3}, \sin\frac{2\pi}{3})$, $C = (\cos\frac{4\pi}{3}, \sin\frac{4\pi}{3})$, then we compute the equation 
$$\overleftrightarrow{B_tC_t} :\qquad 
x\;(1+2 t^2) \;-\; y \;\sqrt{3}\;(1-2 t^2) \;-\; ( 1 - t )( 1 - 2t) \;=\; 0 \tag{2}$$
The ["envelope"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_(mathematics)#Envelope_of_a_family_of_curves) of this family of lines arises from eliminating $t$ from $(2)$ and its derivative with respect to $t$
$$4 xt\;+\;4y t\;\sqrt{3}\;+\; 3 -4 t\;=\;0 \tag{3}$$ 
to obtain this hyperbola:
$$ 8 ( x-1 )^2 - 24 y^2 = 9 \tag{4}$$
Its center is at $A$, and its asymptotes are the extended sides $\overleftrightarrow{AB}$ and $\overleftrightarrow{AC}$. The corresponding envelopes related to vertices $B$ and $C$ are appropriately-rotated copies of this hyperbola:

[image]

Observe that the three hyperbolas are pairwise tangent, and that the medians of the triangle form common tangent lines. In fact, when we restrict our attention in accordance with $(1)$, it turns out that we only care about the hyperbolic arcs determined by the points of tangency. Let's zoom in:

[image]

This curvilinear triangle is cut into six regions by the original triangle's medians. Importantly, and quite clearly, **no tangent line to any one hyperbolic arc enters either of the two regions "opposite" that arc**. We see, then, that a point in the interior of any of those regions lies on three tangent lines; in this figure ...

[image]

... dots indicate how many tangents of a hyperbolic arc meet a given region. At points along the borders between regions ---that is, along the triangle's medians--- "four" tangents can meet, but two of them coincide  with the median, bringing the number of *distinct* tangents down to three. (The center point has ostensibly "six" concurrent tangents ---two per arc--- though obviously only three are distinct.)

Since tangents to the hyperbolic arcs are precisely the triangle's area-bisectors, we have shown that at most three distinct bisectors may concur at a point. $\square$

Comment: What a wonderful answer ! May I ask you which software you have used for your animations ? Geogebra ? Have you seen the animations (http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TriangleAreaBisectors/) ?

Comment: @JeanMarie: Thanks. :) I usually use GeoGebra, but this time I used Mathematica. I had not seen the Demonstration; it's interesting.

Answer (score 1):

The "ratio of areas" being an affine concept (i.e., invariant under affine transforms), we can assume that the triangle is equilateral.

I have erased my previous text answering a question... that hadn't been asked ;)

---

Edit (almost 5 years later) in connection with the answer of @Blue:

If we are looking for an area ratio which is not exactly $1:1$ but slightly different, we have a kind of "defocalization" of the triangle, still with hyperbolic arcs, as illustrated in the following figure:

[image]

extracted from the article by D. Ball, “Halving Envelopes.” The Mathematical Gazette, vol. 64, no. 429, 1980, pp. 166–173, on JSTOR,www.jstor.org/stable/3615118 which gives further details.

Comment: But are there four *concurrent* area-bisectors? (There are certainly three: the medians.)

Comment: It's not *my* question. ;)

Comment: These proofs are very nice, and much more than I expected to get in a response to my question. Jean Marie is right. My question was badly phrased.  I was trying to express it all in one sentence. Luckily for me, the responders who provided these proofs understood what I meant.