# Halving planes of a tetrahedron

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, simplex, envelope

This nice article

> Megan Martin, Cornelia A. Van Cott & Qiyu Zhang (2024) The Beauty of Halving it All, *Math Horizons*, 31:2, 14-17, DOI: 10.1080/10724117.2023.2249357.

shows that the envelope of lines that partition a triangle into two equal area
regions (*halving* lines) consists of three hyperbola arcs.

[image]

My question is: What are the surfaces that form the envelope
of halving planes of a tetrahedron? I'd be interested even in just an
image, if the analytic calculations are too complicated.

---

Answered by Jean Marie:

> Beyer, W. A., and Blair Swartz. "Bisectors of triangles and tetrahedra." *The American Mathematical Monthly* 100, no. 7 (1993): 626-640.

> "The envelope $E$ also consists of seven pieces-it is like a
> heptahedron whose faces have been pinched to tangency along its edges..."

[image: Fig.4]

Comment: Related: ["A question about straight lines that bisect the area of a triangle"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1945535/409). In particular, [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1947242/409) shows those hyperbolic arcs (for an equilateral triangle) and how the bisecting lines/tangents move along them.

Comment: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2323883